# DNS Servers are not forwarding correctly, we talked to CloudFlare, it just won't configure correctly

Tags: linux, dns, ip, cloudflare, a-records

Currently I am using `CloudFlare` for my DNS Settings for my linux server, there I have my Minecraft server IPs, the values are all set to where they should be, and the A records are pointing to the right IPs.

When we look it up or try to connect it gives some random IP that we have no idea where came from

What would cause this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're seeing CloudFlare's IPs & this is normal behavior. Since we act as a reverse proxy for your site, our IPs are going to show in lookups against the domain. We would still be resolving the site to the server IP in your DNS settings.